# How do I deserialize an Rails ActiveRecord serialized field on rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

In my database I have a table for an ActiveRecord type that has a serialized object (stored as "--- !ruby/hash:" followed by classname and key/values separated by newline). I have to reconstruct a part of the database manually and all I have now is a CSV dump of the rows. I am working on a solution to import the objects and restore entries, but I can't find a way to deserialize those serialized hashes. What Object/method is to call to restore these objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a yaml object in your database. You can try the following:

```
YAML::load(your_column)
```

As an example conversion of a column with a Time object:

```
    [1] pry(main)> puts t.request
    --- 2016-06-22 01:23:54.038830166 +03:00
    ...
    => nil
    [2] pry(main)> YAML::load(t.request)
    => 2016-06-22 01:23:54 +0300
    [3] pry(main)> YAML::load(t.request).class
    => Time
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a push into the right direction!